# How to get host url in azure function in queue trigger as input?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have input as queue trigger as below:

```
    [FunctionName("Test")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
       //code
    }
```

I want to get host url of azure function inside above function,
is there any way to get it?

Comment: What is host url and what do you want to do?

Comment: @Mikhail,
I added proxy to azure function to get static assets,
In proxy rules I redirect it to blob storage url, and in blob storage I added all static assets.so for i.e if my host url is: demo.azurewebsites.net(I want this url in azure function)
then in proxy I added something like this:
`{
    "proxies": {
      "path": {
        "matchCondition": {
          "route": "/www/{*path}"
        },
        "backendUri": "https://%STORAGE_HOSTNAME%/demo/www/{path}"
      }
    }
}`
So when I hit this url:https://demo.azurewebsites.net/www/{*path}
it loads from blob.

Comment: How is proxy related to queue trigger? Btw, instead of adding long comments, you should better edit your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the host name by

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")
```

Comment: If trying to build a Url, use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS") to determine if HTTPS is enabled or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can call on any environment variables the host have to your function using:

```
    %VariableName%
```

Use Kudo (https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net) or browse via the portal
[image]

And select the menu/tab "Environment", there you have variables like:
WEBSITE_HOSTNAME or SERVER_NAME and so on. I guess that what you refer to as "host URL" is there and just call it in your code e.g %WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%

Comment: Is there any other way to get it without Env. variable, directly inside function?

Comment: I guess that whenever a http call is made to your function you could read the RequestURI (req.RequestUri) to get the uri that is called. But to me enviroment variables feels much easier.

Comment: Using the GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME") doesn't work when deployed with deployment slots. The app is warmed up and the environment variable is still on the old value. This is not updated until the function is restarted - something you dont want to do to avoid cold starts.